# AWS DynamoDB simple query from DB

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I have a simple table on DynamoDB
with an id and email

I think I created the indexes and now I just want to query for a specific item with a specific email value.

I keep getting errors on that and cant find the right way.

This is my "describe" of the table:

[image]

now how do I query for an item with an email value of "example@example.com"

any help will be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You need to create another index (a Global Secondary Index) only on the `email` field, if you want to be able to query on only that field. You will have to specify the name of the index you want to use as part of the query.

Alternatively, you can do a `scan` instead of a `query`.

Comment: Thanks, can you share an example? And if I have other fields I need to do that for each one?  And I thought i added a keyType range there

Comment: There are plenty of examples in the official DynamoDB documentation of this sort of thing. And yes you can only run a `query` against an index (again, this is covered very well in the documentation). https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Query.html I don't know what you are asking about `keyType`. You created a composite primary key that consists of `userId` and `email`, so you would need to specify those fields if you want to query against that primary index.